# Cocoapods for iOS - Cant Load Libraries

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I'm using Cocoapods to install the following package in a brand new iOS project in Xcode.

https://github.com/jpsim/JPSVolumeButtonHandler

After adding `pod 'JPSVolumeButtonHandler'` to my `Podfile` and running `pod install`, I close the existing Xcode project and open the new xcworkspace file

If I then try to `#import 'JPSVolumeButtonHandler.h'` in `my ViewController.h` file, I get an error:

```
JPSVolumeButtonHandler file not found
```

I know this can sometimes be resolved by building the project, but even after doing so, I still get the same error.  Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured this out.  In past Cocoapod libraries I had used, there was a single global file to be included that lived outside of the cocoapod library's directory.

In this case, I had to provide the full path from my `Pod Root` to the the header file I needed, which is located at pods/JPSVolumeButtonHandler/JPSVolumeButtonHandler.h

So my import statement now looks like:

```
#import "JPSVolumeButtonHandler/JPSVolumeButtonHandler.h"
```